# Benchmarking with mlr3

Tags: r, benchmarking, mlr3

I am not able to understand the behavior of mlr3 benchmarking. I developed 6 models and I used nested CV for each of them tuning hyperparameters (e.g. 2 hyperparameter for the rpart learner). On my desktops, each model takes about 10 minutes. I then use benchmarking for the 6 models, but after two hours the benchmarking process has not ended yet. I would like to understand why it takes more with the benchmarking than with the individual models; is this to be expected normally or it is I that make a mistake somewhere? I would also like to understand what would be the best option to reasonably compare (benchmark) multiple models (5-10-20 models) in a more efficient manner. For other 6 models it took me 48 hours to finish, and my attempts to parallelize it did not result in performance improvement (presumably because I work on Windows, where future R package does not work ideally). Many thanks!

Comment: This depends on how you set up the hyperparameter tuning (range of values, number of evaluations). Tuning runs can do hundreds or thousands of model evaluations. There's no general rule for what constitutes a "reasonable" comparison -- it depends on the models, datasets, etc.

Comment: Hard to say without a minimal example, to make sure that we are on the same page. Did you use AutoTuner and `resample()` for single nested reampling and multiple AutoTuners and `benchmark()` to do the benchmark? Maybe your benchmark grid includes unwanted runs?

Comment: Yes, I used AutoTuner and resample() for single nested resampling and multiple AutoTuners and benchmark() to do the benchmark. The same single nested resamplings (6 ) were combined in a benchmark grid. And then it took 48 hours. I do not know how to chekc whether the benchmark grid includes unwanted runs, because the grid is relatively cryptic to me (it shows something like 6 rows of <TaskClassif[46]> <GraphLearner[33]> <ResamplingCV[19]>).

Comment: I should add that the data set is relatively small, 781 observations, that is why 48 hours seems too long to me.

Comment: It seems it was the "relief" filter I added, which prolonged unreasonably the process. I eliminate it and it worked very fast. Thank you for your help.